# How to get columns from joined table in django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

Keeping the problem simple :

Trying to Learn ORM.

And now I am stuck with simple left join issue .

So Lets start with basic model :

```
class City(models.Model):
    city=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pin_code = models.IntegerField(null=False)

class State(models.Model)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Now, I basically want to do :

```
select c.pin_code 
from 
  State s 
left join City c on s.city = c.city;
```

The equivalent of above in ORM that I could grasp from the mighty World Wide Web is :

```
State.objects.select_related('city')
```

The above querset on looping through gives me only data from State Table .
I dont get 'pin_code' column .

I did all the search possible on the internet , but couldnt find any solution .

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just access it by following relationship

```
states = State.objects.select_related('city')

for state in states:
    state.city.pin_code
```